# Strange CPU usage when I touch (or a little shake)

Tags: central-processing-unit

I've got a setup on a ASUS Z10-PAU8 MB and Xeon 1620 v4 + Corsair RMx 850W + 1 HDD + 1 SSD.

We noticed that, with the slightest touch (little shake the table where server temporarily lays) of the server, the CPU load is greatly increasing (99%) and sometimes its just hangs.

Continuing the investigation, we tried to shake it pretty hard and the indicator "CATERR1" on the motherboard up in red and server hangs.

In windows journal we have a lot of messages with "WHEA Logger - Error type: Memory controller error" when this happens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQMj9.jpg

We tried another DIMM module, no luck, same problem, pins on cpu socket all looks ok.

Well be glad if someone have any ideas about this behavior.

Comment: Just replace the board. It's not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the board is done with. It sounds like a contact is borked, either on the DIMM socket, the CPU socket or a solder point somewhere in between.

You could try wiggling the DIMMs or CPU socket/heat sink carefully if that also causes the problem. Additionally, you could use slight tapping with a fingertip (make sure you're completely discharged and grounded) to narrow down the problem geographically.

Alternatively, you might get away with leaving a DIMM socket empty - try with a single DIMM if you can narrow it down to a specific socket.

It could be anywhere between RAM and CPU though. For a server, I'd replace the board.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. On the back side of the MB are bent legs at the RAM slot, I fixed it up and everything is fine now.

Comment: I'd be very wary using that computer for anything important.